# Citrix Receiver: IE8 issue

Tags: security, citrix

we are using here Citrix Receiver to navigate through Internet Explorer 8.

Unfortunately we have an user that sometimes opening IE8, got the following message on the top bar:

"Your current security settings put your computer at risk. Click here to change your security settings...". At the same time the personal setting (zoom) are not loaded. The user need to close the session and re-open it again several times to don't get this warning message and have the proper user-custom profile loaded (zoom).

We already tried to update the citrix receiver version, without any effect.

What can be done to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked quite a while ago but but I'm putting this here in case anyone else needs assistance:

**I would suggest running the Citrix Cleanup Utility and reinstalling the Receiver before attempting anything else.** Whenever multiple versions of the receiver have been installed they don't always play nice, even if you have uninstalled before installing. This utility should fully remove the receiver including any registry entries and other junk left behind. Here's a link to the utility: [Receiver Clean-Up Utility](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX137494?download)